# Xcode Instruments Time Profiler Understanding which methods are taking the most time

Tags: xcode, user-interface, profiling, calayer, xcode-instruments

My UI is acting choppy and I am trying to understand what the source for this is.

There are a lot of options using Xcode Instruments and I am not sure which set of them are the best for me.

From playing around with some of them it seems that most time is spent in `[CALayer drawInContext]` and `[CALayer layoutSublayers]` but I have no idea in what context those methods are called from (what part of the UI is doing that).

Which options should I be choosing in order to better understand?

Also would like to know if there is a way to see what is running in the background which doesn't belong to the current visible UI (I think something in the background may also be thrashing the CPU)

Answer (score 1):

Toogle Display of Primary Views and select:

- Separated by Thread
- Invert Call Tree
- Hide System Libraries
- Show Obj-C Only

Try to see this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Use the instruments Time Profiler instrument to record your app running on the device during its choppy moments.

Upload the instruments trace at:
http://timeanalyzer.excelsis.com

It will give you a timeline view of your main thread (the main place where UI stutters occur) methods that's a lot easier to visualize than the regular instruments UI. Here's an example view:

http://timeanalyzer.excelsis.com/view.php?jobid=c7f3efc43ff85302a80515b56c0900f0

Comment: These links are dead